# Swift 3 retrieve value from nested JSON Array

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hi I am currently learning Swift 3, and I have an app I am "developing" to provide weather for a specific location.

I have got my MetOffice API and retrieved the JSON required.  I am able to retrieve the location without issue, but when I try to get the temp data I get no result.  The temp data is listed as DM in the JSON and is an array within an array within a dictionary within  dictionary.

my current code looks like

```
   if let SiteRep = dict["SiteRep"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        if let DV = SiteRep["DV"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            if let location = DV["Location"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let period = location["Period"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    if let Rep = period["Rep"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                        if let DM = Rep[0]["DM"] as? Double {
                            self._currentTemp = DM
    } } } } } }
```

relevant vars are declared above this.

I'm not sure how to correct this code to pull this required value back from the JSON

Json as follows, the value i am trying to retrieve is highlighted in bold

```
{  
   "SiteRep":{  
      "Wx":{  },
      "DV":{  
         "dataDate":"2017-02-10T12:00:00Z",
         "type":"Forecast",
         "Location":{  
            "i":"350497",
            "lat":"99.6115",
            "lon":"-21.0017",
            "name":"TOWN",
            "country":"ENGLAND",
            "continent":"EUROPE",
            "elevation":"160.0",
            "Period":[  
               {  
                  "type":"Day",
                  "value":"2017-02-10Z",
                  "Rep":[  
                     {  
                        "D":"NE",
                        "Gn":"16",
                        "Hn":"77",
                        "PPd":"51",
                        "S":"9",
                        "V":"GO",
                        **"Dm":"2",**
                        "FDm":"-2",
                        "W":"24",
                        "U":"1",
                        "$":"Day"
                     },
                     {  
                        "D":"NNW",
                        "Gm":"20",
                        "Hm":"89",
                        "PPn":"58",
                        "S":"11",
                        "V":"GO",
                        "Nm":"-1",
                        "FNm":"-6",
                        "W":"24",
                        "$":"Night"
                     }
```

Comment: You are looking for DM but JSON key is Dm i think there is the issue, its a key so its case sensisitve

Comment: Hi, sorry i did notice this after I posted and edited my code, but still the same, no value returned.

Comment: What about parsing to another number type like int?

Comment: Anyway if you can use a framework i recomend Swifty JSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. Its pretty easy to handle json with that so check it out

Comment: interstingly, it didnt work as an int, but it does as a string, thank you for the tip

Comment: It's because you put it between quotations... "2". If it's an integer or a double it can't be written as a string.